# How to create url route for specific Controller and Action in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I am working in Asp.net mvc3 application.I have created url for product detail page like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "ProductDetail",
   "{category}/{title}-{id}",
   new { controller = "ProductDetail", action = "Index" }
);
```

for other controller using this

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default",   
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",    
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Following code creating this url

`www.example.com/Shoes/blackshoes-100`

Now Problem is that i want to use this url for ProductDetail page if add any other controller and action name it will redirect to ProductDetail page like this

`www.example.com/Home/Index-100`

How can i restrict this url for ProductDetail Page?

is this right way to do this?

I wan to hide Controller and Action of Productdetail page.

Category,title and id values are changing for every product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define routes for any other page you have and map those routes before you map your peoduct detail route. Then the route maching mechanism will find them first and use them.

Of course you do not have to map route for every single action. You can create some prefixes for example for diffrent controllers like example below, to catch all routes for Home controller actions:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "Home/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Comment: yes i am using this route for other controller.but when use url like this www.example.com/Home/Index-100 . here home controller and Index action treated like category,and title

Comment: If you mean the default route like in your question then it can't work.. you have to specify such route for each controller.. also you have to remember to register this route before you will register your `ProductDetails` route.